# how to get minimum prefix from a large file

Tags: shell, awk

I have a big file whose entries are like this . 
Input:

```
1113
1113456
11134567
12345
1734
123
194567
```

From this entries , I need to find out the minimum number of prefix which can represent all these entries. 
Expected output:

```
1113
123
1734
194567
```

If we have 1113 then there is no need to use 1113456 or 1113457.

Things I have tried:
I can use `grep -v ^123` and compare with input file and store the unique results in the output file. IF I use a while loop , I dont know , how I can delete the entries from the input file itself.

Comment: Why isn't the answer just "1"?

Comment: `If we have 1113 then there is no need to use 1113456 or 1113457. ` - if you have `1` there is no need to use `1113` and `123`. Why isn't the answer `1`? Why is `123` in the expected output? Why didn't you compare `123` with `1113` when searching for the shortest prefix?

Comment: The numbers which I have are actually like phone number prefix. So we dont want to  reduce the number which have already been provided . So the logic is 123 will be assigned to an operator like Reliance. So If the number is either 123 or 123456 , we will be mapping to Reliance. So I dont want to add extra entries in the table by putting 123 as well as 123456 to Relance.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk` command:

```
awk '{
   n = (n != "" && index($1, n) == 1 ? n : $1)
}
p != n {
   print p = n
}' <(sort file)
```

```
1113
123
1734
194567
```

Comment: So for both the solution did not work. You can check with these input 
790234
790835
795023
79788
7985904
7902713
791
7987
7988
709576
749576
7902712
790856
79780
798599
791453
791454
791455
791456
791457
791458
791459
791460  . In the output I expect to have only 791 and other number with 790 range. But I could see in addition to 791 we have 791453,791454 etc

Comment: @user1107731 I fixed my solution. anubhava assumed that your file was sorted (which is the case in the sample you provided - that is why choosing a good sample of data for stack is very important). You can use his command by replacing `file` with `<(sort file)`

Comment: Thanks @CorentinLimier, yes indeed I assumed file is sorted as in the question. `<(sort file)` instead of `file` will be the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that input file is:

```
790234
790835
795023
79788
7985904
7902713
791
7987
7988
709576
749576
7902712
790856
79780
798599
791453
791454
791455
791456
791457
791458
791459
791460
```

You can use

```
awk '!(prev && $0~prev){prev = "^" $0; print}' <(sort file)
```

Returns

```
709576
749576
790234
7902712
7902713
790835
790856
791
795023
79780
79788
7985904
798599
7987
7988
```

How does it work ? First it sorts the file using lexicographic sort (1 < 10 < 2). Then it keeps the minimal prefix and checks if next lines match. If they do they are skipped. If a line doesn't, it will update the minimal prefix and prints the line.

Let's say that input is

```
71
82
710
```

First it orders the lines and input becomes (lexicographic sort : 71 < 710 < 82) :

```
71
710
82
```

First line is printed because awk variable `prev` is not set so condition `!(prev && $0~prev)` is reached. `prev` becomes `71`. On next row, `710` will match regexp `^71` so line is skipped and `prev` variable stays `71`. On next row, `82`does not match `^71`, condition `!(prev && $0~prev)` is reached again, line is printed, `prev` is set  to `82`.

Comment: , May you please  elaborate. Lets say input is 71 710 82. awk '!(prev && $0~prev){prev = "^" $0; print}'

Comment: @user1107731 I added explanations based on your  example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || (index($0,n)!=1){n=$0; print}' <(sort file)
1113
123
1734
194567
```